# Django tests pass locally but not on Github Actions push

Tags: sql, django, github, testing, github-actions

My tests pass locally and in fact on Github Actions it also says "ran 8 tests" and then "OK" (and I have 8). However, the test stage fails due to a strange error in the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SCHEMA": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/store/store/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/runner/work/store/store/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 736, in run_tests
    self.teardown_databases(old_config)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 41, in teardown_databases
    self._wipe_tables(connection)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 26, in _wipe_tables
    cursor.execute(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.9/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "SCHEMA": syntax error
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

These are all just default Django files and I haven't messed with any of them. I don't really know what to do about it and internet searches yield nothing helpful.

Comment: is your web site hosted on heroku ? because in heroku you can not use sqlite.

Comment: Yes, it is but it works fine. The databases and images all work properly; the only problem is the tests in Github Actions.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue. For me I had django_heroku in my project settings.py. It looks like, based on the comments that your app is using this.
I had something like this in settings.py:

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

change to the following so it doesn't use django_heroku on github actions:

```
if os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT') != 'github':
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

and then declare an environment variable in the workflow file, I have this:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7, 3.8, 3.9, '3.10']
    env: 
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "someKey"
      ENVIRONMENT: github
```

Note: this is assuming you have environment variables setup. I know there are different ways of doing it, so depending on how they are setup you might have to change how they are accessed

more info [here](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/39)

edit:

As per the comments, you don't have to declare an additional environment variable because github has a default variable called GITHUB_ACTIONS

so you can do

```
if os.environ.get('GITHUB_ACTIONS') != 'true': 
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: I would suggest to use default github variable `GITHUB_ACTIONS` and check
`if os.environ.get('GITHUB_ACTIONS') != 'true'` but yeah, it works. Upvoted.
More info on default github environment variables [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables).

Comment: I did not know about that, I will update my answer. Thanks!